# Xcode 11.2 assistant layout greyed out

Tags: xcode

I can't change the layout of the assistant editor in Xcode 11.2.
So the matching code of the storyboard is always on the right which drives me crazy bc I'm working with 21" screen.
The phenomen appears when updating Xcode from 11.1 to 11.2.
The Layout can be seen, but its greyed out. I cannot choose the available options Editor on left , Editor on top.
I've tried to change editor orientation, but have no success.
Opening a second editor below shows the assistant editor of the new editor pane on the right too?!

Answer (score 35):

Updated for Xcode 13.x.x

You might've accidentally enabled `Focus Mode` which I just realized was the reason I couldn't open additional Editors:

Turn Focus Mode `off` and you should be able to add Editors as expected.

**View > Editor > Toggle Focus (Hide Focus)**

Shortcut: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>

[image]

Comment: This is correct and useful!   Do you know what this "Focus" functionality is for?

Comment: It's useful when you have split your Xcode screen in several ways and you temporarily want to see just one file. @delta2flat

Comment: disabling focus has fixed that for me in Xcode 12.1

Answer (score -1):

Switched back to Xcode 10.2.1 with symlinking 13.x devices by Xcode 11.2 installation.